# Spinner not showing list of options from list of strings

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a spinner with list of locale months (or string in general). I already checked a few tutorials on this topic and had this running using string-array and ArrayAdapter.createFromResource() but i need to also show dynamic things like filtered list of years etc.
My activity:

```
class ChartActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val view by lazy { ActivityChartBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setSpinners()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart)
}

private fun setSpinners() {
    setMonthSpinner()
}

private fun setMonthSpinner() {
    var months = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().shortMonths
    var monthsAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, months)
    monthsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    view.spinnerMonth.adapter = monthsAdapter
}
}
```

activity xml:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerMonth"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerYear"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Spinners (without values) are visible in emulator, click on them triggers visual effects, but doesn't show value list

[image: emulator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not using your inflated binding in `setContentView` you're setting the layout again `setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart)` but you're updating view using `view.spinnerMonth`. This won't have effect.

So the correct way would be set `setContentView(view.root)`.

So your activity would look like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val view by lazy { ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(view.root)
        setSpinners()
    }

    private fun setSpinners() {
        setMonthSpinner()
    }

    private fun setMonthSpinner() {
        var months = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().shortMonths
        var monthsAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, months)
        monthsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        view.spinnerMonth.adapter = monthsAdapter
    }
}
```